# MongoDB server can still be accessed without credentials

Tags: mongodb

I have a fresh mongodb server (2.6.0) in my machine and I started the mongod instance with the following config file:

```
dbpath = c:\mongo\data\db
port = 27017
logpath = c:\mongo\data\logs\mongo.log
auth = true
```

Later, I connected to this mongod instance through mongo shell and created an admin user:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "tugberk",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles:
    [
      {
        role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        db: "admin"
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

Then, I logged out from the shell and reconnect with the following command:

```
mongo --host localhost --port 27017 -u tugberk -p 12345678 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Then, I created a user with root access:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "tugberkRoot",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)
```

The last step is not necessary here but the anonymous access now should have been fully disabled. However, I can still connect to it anonymously through mongo shell (even if I don't have any access to do anything):

[image]

What should I do to prevent any anonymous connection?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Authentication prevents you from performing actions on the database (as your screenshot shows - you can't even list databases), it doesn't prevent connections - after all, you have to be able to connect to be able to authenticate.

There is a [feature request to add timeouts](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12418), but for now this is essentially how the server is meant to behave.

It's worth noting that up until you try to do something, this is really no different than just connecting to the port with `telnet` - the text displayed at the start "connecting to:" etc. is from the client, not the server.  As soon as it tries to do anything unauthenticated, even list the server warnings, an error is thrown because it does not have sufficient permissions.

If you want to lock down things from a connection perspective, the only option from a MongoDB perspective is to restrict the IP addresses it listens on (default is all) using the [`bindIp`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) option.  Using `127.0.0.1` would lock it down to local usage for example (but you would then be unable to connect from a remote host), which makes replication an issue so be careful when choosing your bound address.

Outside MongoDB, you should look at locking things down from a firewall perspective.  On Linux this would be [IPTables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), [hosts.allow/deny](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:security:inetd) or similar.  Windows firewall is not my area of expertise, but I would imagine you can do similar there also.

Comment: bummer :s so, there is probably no way for me to hide the server existence for anonymous connections. At least at the MonogDB level. thx!

Comment: added relevant bits of my original response to the answer for clarity

Comment: If client dont know password, mysql process will not even listen to it. Why cant mongod? mongod wastes its power in servicing unauthenticated users(till they dont send **db.auth()**). This is what OP dont want. I guess its impossible for firewalls, to distinguish between authenticated users, and unauthenticated users because of the way mongod behaves.

Comment: MySQL does allow connections prior to authentication, unless you are using whitelists/blacklists to only allow connections from certain IP addresses.  If you don't believe me, just try connecting to a MySQL database with telnet or similar, it will connect, then boot you out when you don't continue as it expects.  There is no way to authenticate a user without first allowing them to connect, anyone that thinks there is fundamentally does not understand how networking actually functions.

Comment: Very simple abuse: enter "while(1);" into a Mongo console that you haven't authenticated on. It will happily eat up all its own resources running that single line, and you don't even need to log in to do it.

Comment: which is basically a DOS attack that is possible for any application that listens on a TCP port (TCP does not do auth, this is not unique to MongoDB). You can do your while loop even more efficiently without the mongo shell, hell you can leave out the full connection and just do a SYN flood while you are at it. That is why people put things like load balancers, firewalls etc. in front of these applications and only allow trusted clients to connect to them - your database (any database) should never be open to the public so that this would be a concern

Comment: Except that all DDOS attacks you have mentioned are preventable upstream. mongodb adds a layer of attacks, and by allowing access to its shell even without authentication widens the attack surface. Now of course everything is preventable if you take care, reality is, a lot of devs in the real world don't take care, making mongodb a real threat.

Comment: and the same is true of anything that listens on a port, the shell is just a local process, no different than a bash shell that lets you connect to something. Your argument makes absolutely no sense, sorry

Comment: @KaeVerens Wasn't it executed locally? The shell that enters `while` will eat the resource (but only one core), not the server.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can protect your databases by enabling authentication in security section of the mongo.conf file like this:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: But you can always access the mongo shell before authentication.

Comment: Legacy mongodb.conf format uses `auth=true` which is still coming with Ubuntu 20.04 aptitude with mongodb 3.6, just a note.