# mongodb authentication . login prevent

Tags: mongodb, security

I'm a beginner to `mongodb`,I have a installed `mongodb` 2.6 on windows. Now, I want to prevent any `login` without authentication. I read `localhost exception` manual from docs.mongodb.org. after reading that manual, I created a `userAdminAnyDatabase` with

```
use admin
db.createUser
(
    {
        user: "adminDB",
        pwd: "password", 
        roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase","readWriteAnyDatabase","root" ]
    }
)
```

localhost exception must disable automatically. I use this command to start mongodb server.

`mongod --auth --setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0 --setParameter enableTestCommands=0 --dbpath "D:\data"`

I still can login with mongo.exe and can see databases name. but I can't change,update or drop anything. Is there anyway to prevent any login ? and prevent anyone to read databases names?

Comment: Did you [create your system administrator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#create-the-system-user-administrator) in the `admin` db (i.e. `use admin`, first)? If so, `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` should be redundant as that should be automatically disabled. Similarly, `enableTestCommands` defaults to 0 so you should not need to specify this either. Since you have explicitly disabled the localhost bypass in your command line, you should be getting an error like `"not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }"` when trying to list databases.

Comment: What does `db.version()` report?

Comment: yes Stennie.db version 2.6.3.
i'm delete all other users. and create new admin with full accese any database and `readwitre` permission to any database.now i'am confused.
localhost exeptions bug.
int the first time that i run `mongod` server and login with `mongo` and logout . after that , i see all of my bin folder has been deleted !!! i dont khow why?! again i install mongodb.
2 bug in first work not good.

Comment: i get `not authorized on admin to execute command` when i login without any `auth` (use --auth and create a admin user and enableLocalhostAuthBypass option) and try to update or change in a database.

Comment: i found same problem . link to :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387689/mongodb-server-can-still-be-accessed-without-credentials?rq=1

Comment: As noted in the answer from @amenadiel, it is expected that you can connect to MongoDB since the authentication details are provided *after* connecting. Assuming all is configured correctly, you will not be able to list databases or create any data as an unauthorized user. Note: this is not a bug; this is how authentication protocols work. As for as your `bin` directory being deleted .. it sounds like there must be some other accidental interaction going on. Is this a shared or public server? Is it possible someone else is changing the config as well?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: i think this is useless now. and i already flagged it btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior of having the MongoDB auth enabled.

1. You establish a connection with the MongoDB server
2. you specify against which database you need to authenticate
3. you validate your credentials

For anyone to be able to authenticate, you actually need to allow them to reach point 3.

Comment: its true but still i can login with localhost.  
its a bug . but i don't know its from me or from mongo.   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387689/mongodb-server-can-still-be-accessed-without-credentials?rq=1

we must use firewall

Comment: I assume you have restarted the mongo service after changing its conf file, right? Can you post your config file to check it out? When you say you can still log in, does it mean you can perform ```collection.find``` commands or just ```use db``` commands?

Comment: i config mongod in cmd.exe .
any change or update or find for other database have not permission.
pure mongo.exe login to test database!! but i dont have test!!
i delete every thing and create new db!! idont know whats that?!

Comment: you don't need to be logged to use the ```use database``` command, and there's no need for that database name to actually exist. You can try ```use superdatabase``` while unlogged and it'll still work, until you try to perform any db command, that is. This is because when you declare ```use whatevername``` you're not doing anything except for pointing your next command to a given namespace.

Comment: @amenadiel, technically what you say is not correct. If you're connected and do "use whatever" there is interaction with the server, therefore additional resources used. It could be used for a denial of service attack, perhaps. I just mean to point out "use xxx" is not *solely* handled in the client.